# Inherit a widget in js odoo 16

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-16

There is an edit that I made on the search more option, I need it to be shown all the time,
in odoo 14, i made it by this code :

```
    odoo.define('customized_m2o_widget.Fields', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var relational_fields = require('web.relational_fields');
    var FieldMany2One = relational_fields.FieldMany2One;

    FieldMany2One.include({
    _search: async function (searchValue = "") {
    const value = searchValue.trim();
    const domain = this.record.getDomain(this.recordParams);
    const context = Object.assign(
    this.record.getContext(this.recordParams),
    this.additionalContext
    );
    var values = await this._super.apply(this, arguments);

    if (this.limit >= values.length || this.limit < values.length) {
    values = this._manageSearchMore(values, value, domain, context);
    }

    return values;
    },
    })
    });
```

now I need to migrate to odoo 16, so anyone have a way to do it in the write syntax and semantic code to let it works again?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to patch the [many2one_field](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/web/static/src/views/fields/many2one/many2one_field.js#L142) widget and set the search limit to `-1`

***Example:***

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import {patch} from "@web/core/utils/patch";
import {Many2OneField} from "@web/views/fields/many2one/many2one_field";

patch(Many2OneField.prototype, "Many2OneField.SearchMore", {
    get Many2XAutocompleteProps() {
        return {
            ...this._super(...arguments),
            searchLimit: -1,
        };
    }
});
```

Add the following entry to the manifest file:

```py
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        'MODULE_NAME/static/src/js/many2one_search_more.js',
    ],
},
```

***Update***

Inherit `relational_utils` to override `loadOptionsSource` function

***Example:***

```js
import {patch} from "@web/core/utils/patch";
import { Many2XAutocomplete } from "@web/views/fields/relational_utils"


patch(Many2XAutocomplete.prototype, "Many2XAutocomplete.SearchLimit", {

    async loadOptionsSource(request) {
        var options = this._super(request);
        return options;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, maybe my question wasn't clear, I don't need to  make it static on specific number, i need it to let it be shown all the time, with preserve to the search limit = to 7
this is the function that i would like to change called loadOptionsSource inside the file :addons/web/static/src/views/fields/relational_utils.js
so if you can help me just to find the right way to inherite I'll be thankfull!

Comment: I added an example how to overrode the `loadOptionsSource` function in `addons/web/static/src/views/fields/relational_utils.js`